# ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor Partial View but specify 'depth' of layouts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a View that has a 'intermediate' layout, which in turn has a 'base' layout.

This creates a full web page. However, I want to do partial page updates using Ajax, but to be able to do that at two levels:

1. The View level with no layout - easy with PartialView()
2. The View with the intermediate layout but not the 'base' layout.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller action that is supposed to do case 2) you could pass to the view some information in the view model indicating this:

In the view:

```
@{
    if (Model.IsIntermediateLayout) {
        Layout = "IntermediateLayout.cshtml";
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks - that gave me the inspiration to set the level in the Controller (depending on the Action called), and then specifying the Layout in the View(s) according to this.